# after effects - motion graphics/kinetic text

Tags: after-effects, motion, motion-graphics

Attempting to replicate this graphic. How can I replicate and be sure to have the squeezing effect as well as the subtle motion blur

I plan for the graphic I'm working on have text that remains static to the left with additional text to the right compresses to the right and changes.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text in after effects can have animators applied at the character, word or line level. The animators work kinda differently to normal animated properties in that the property that gets animated usually doesn't have keyframes, but is instead controlled by a **selector** which is comprised of a group of controls that determine what part of the text is to have the modification applied. Normally you animate the selector to add animation to the individual parts of the text.

Select your text layer and choose `Animation>Animate Text>Position` from the top menu or from the `Add` menu for the animator group in the Timeline panel. If you add some X offset to the position property that appears in the new animator group, and play with the selector beginning, end, and offset values you'll get a bit of an idea.

Now once you've fiddled with it for a bit, and probably got confused, head on over to the [manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/animating-text.html) and give it a read.

As far as Motion Blur goes, if you turn on motion blur for the layer, and make sure it is on in your render settings you'll be golden. If you want to see it while you're working (at the price of much slower previews) turn on motion blur in the timeline window. How you do all that is also (surprise!) in the [manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/assorted-animation-tools.html#motion_blur).

Comment: Thank you so much! this set me on the right track.

Comment: As they say on Youtube, "like and subscribe". Or more precisely, if it answers your question, hit the tick to mark it as correct—it helps others find the answer too.